# Pydev run unittests selectively

Tags: python, eclipse, unit-testing, pydev

When I use Java with JUnit in Eclipse, I can highlight a method name in a unit test file and run only that single test. Is something like this available in PyDev? I don't want to run all my tests in a file all the time, only a single one.

Answer (score 3):

In PyDev you must do Ctrl+F9 and then select the test to run.

Also, it may be nice reading: http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html as it gives some more hints on running modules within PyDev.